# Line Filter in Power Supply question

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, line

I have faulty power supply in my digital reverb unit and after replacing all capacitors the problem is still there - fast on/off switching with clicking sound. It does turn on sometimes though but rarely. So I have decided to buy whole new power supply board instead, since it is not expensive.

"Mean Well RT-50C" is what I am going to buy. And my question is about line filter, because in my reverb unit (Dynacord DRP-15) has dedicated line filter board which is connected to power supply and I am not sure if RT-50C does contain some line filter circuit already or not. I want to know if I should remove the stock line filter also or keep it there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The MW supply will have a line filter on board. That said, there’s no harm in keeping the existing line filter. It won’t cause a malfunction and may actually help.